# getStaticPaths and getStaticProps with moralis query

Tags: reactjs, json, next.js, moralis

I have been to make getStaticPaths and getStaticProps to work but somehow I feel like I'm missing something. I tried to query inside each of them which I think it is repetitive but I have no idea on how to do it.
Can anyone show me an example?

Here's my code:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  // Call an external API endpoint to get posts.
  // You can use any data fetching library

  const { data, error, isLoading } = useMoralisQuery(
    "Posts",
    (query) => query.equalTo("objectId", postObjID),
    [postObjID]
  );
  const postDetailstringfied = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
  // By returning { props: { posts } }, the Blog component
  // will receive `posts` as a prop at build time
  return {
    props: {
      postDetailstringfied,
    },
  };
}
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  // When this is true (in preview environments) don't
  // prerender any static pages
  // (faster builds, but slower initial page load)
  if (process.env.SKIP_BUILD_STATIC_GENERATION) {
    return {
      paths: [],
      fallback: "blocking",
    };
  }

  // Call an external API endpoint to get posts
  const { data, error, isLoading } = useMoralisQuery(
    "Posts",
    (query) => query,
    []
  );
  const postDetailstringfied = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));

  // Get the paths we want to prerender based on posts
  // In production environments, prerender all pages
  // (slower builds, but faster initial page load)
  const paths = postDetailstringfied.map((post) => ({
    params: { id: post.id },
  }));

  // { fallback: false } means other routes should 404
  return { paths, fallback: false };
}
```

Comment: What's the issue? Note that `useMoralisQuery` is a React hook, it cannot be used inside `getStaticProps`/`getStaticPaths`. These are functions that run on the server at build time.

Comment: I see, that's probably the main issue that I have. How can I turn the data the I have on moralis and use it inside getStatisProps or Paths?

Comment: In the support chat they said I have to pick the function from here https://docs.moralis.io/moralis-dapp/database/queries and I have no idea which one to use for this.

Answer (score 1):

react hooks won't work server side. You can use the vanilla js syntax provided [here](https://v1docs.moralis.io/moralis-dapp/database/queries)

In your case the alternative would be

```js
const Posts = Moralis.Object.extend("Posts");
const query = new Moralis.Query(Posts);
query.equalTo("objectId", postObjID);
const results = await query.find();
```